# Bootstrap Date Paginator datepicker width

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How can i change Bootstrap Date Paginator  width.

it said in documentation to use `Integer. Default: 35` [source](https://github.com/jonmiles/bootstrap-datepaginator)

How can i aplly it on below code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var options = {
        //selectedDate: '2016-01-01',
        selectedDateFormat: 'DD-MMM-YYYY',
        Default: 0
    }

    $('#paginator').datepaginator(options);

    $('#paginator').datepaginator();


    $('#paginator').on('selectedDateChanged', function (event, date) {
        $('#<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>').val(date);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see the documantion it should be like this

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var options = {
            //selectedDate: '2016-01-01',
            selectedDateFormat: 'DD-MMM-YYYY',
            itemWidth: your width integer here
        }

        $('#paginator').datepaginator(options);
    });
```